# Moving records in between rows in same table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I need to add Qty and Dayssupply from  RXBatch (Test1) to another Rxbatch (Test2) by prescription, where the patid, facid, and ndc matches. Once the qty and dayssuply is added to from test1 to test2, I need test1 qty and dayssuply to be zero. 
 [tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M4ost.png)

Below is what I’ve been working on, but my script only adds qty to both batches and doesn’t zero out qty once its added.

```
UPDATE RXS
SET QTY=RXS_Totals.Qty_Total
FROM FWDB.RX.RXS RXS
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT FacID, PatID, NDC, SUM(Qty) AS Qty_Total
  FROM FWDB.RX.RXS
  WHERE RxBatch='test1' OR RxBatch='test2'
  GROUP BY FacID, PatID, NDC
  HAVING MIN(RxBatch) <> MAX(RxBatch)
) AS RXS_Totals ON RXS_Totals.FacID = RXS.FacID AND
  RXS_Totals.PatID = RXS.PatID AND
  RXS_Totals.NDC = RXS.NDC
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: I have added the image of sample data. website doesn't allow me to display it. It requires reputation of 10 points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're doing a self-join, if so, you could do something like this :

```
UPDATE rx
SET 
    Qty = (CASE WHEN rx.RxBatch = rx1.RxBatch THEN 0 ELSE rx1.Qty + rx2.Qty END), 
    DaysSupply = (CASE WHEN rx.RxBatch = rx1.RxBatch THEN 0 ELSE rx1.DaysSupply + rx2.DaysSupply END)
FROM RXS rx
LEFT JOIN RXS rx1 ON rx1.RxNo = rx.RxNo AND rx1.RxBatch = 'TEST1'
LEFT JOIN RXS rx2 ON rx2.RxNo = rx.RxNo AND rx2.RxBatch = 'TEST2'
WHERE 
        rx1.PatID = rx2.PatID
    AND rx1.FacID = rx2.FacID
    AND rx1.NDC = rx2.NDC
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need:

```
UPDATE RXS
    SET QTY = (CASE WHEN RxBatch = 'test2' THEN RXS_Totals.Qty_Total ELSE 0 END)
    FROM . . .
    WHERE RxBatch IN ('test1', 'test2');
```